# NoReverseMatch at /app02/user_delete-5/

Tags: django

In my `/templates/app02/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^userinfo/', views.userinfo),
    url(r'^user_delete-(?P<nid>\d+)/', views.user_delete),
]
```

In the `/app02/views.py`:

```
def userinfo(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        # QuerySet
        user_list = models.UserInfo.objects.all()

        return render(request, 'app02/userinfo.html', {'user_list':user_list})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        u = request.POST.get('username')
        p = request.POST.get('password')
        models.UserInfo.objects.create(
            username=u,
            password=p
        )
        print ('before redirect')
        return redirect('/app02/userinfo/') 

def user_delete(request, nid):
    models.UserInfo.objects.filter(id=nid).delete()
    return redirect(request, '/app02/userinfo/')
```

This is the code in the template:

```
    <ul>
        {% for row in user_list  %}
        <li>
            <a href="/app02/user_detail-{{row.id}}/">{{ row.username }} </a> |
            <a href="/app02/user_delete-{{row.id}}/">delete</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But after I delete the item in browser,
I get the below error in browser:

> NoReverseMatch at /app02/user_delete-5/

Please attention the data is delete success, but the browser gets the error, but did not redirect to the `/app02/userinfo/`.(See my `user_delete` method in the `/app02/views.py`)
And in the browser address bar url is:`http://localhost:8000/app02/user_delete-4/` .

---

**EDIT**

The full traceback:

```
NoReverseMatch at /app02/user_delete-4/
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/app02/user_delete-4/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/app02/user_delete-4/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/app02/user_delete-4/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/app02/user_delete-4/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/app02/user_delete-4/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/pyProject',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
Server time:    Mon, 14 Aug 2017 04:27:10 +0000
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return redirect(request, '/app02/userinfo/')
```

`redirect` does not take `request` as an argument. It is trying to find a URL to match the string representation of the `request` object, which is `"<WSGIRequest: GET '/app02/user_delete-4/'>"` and of course that will fail because you don't have such a pattern.

So, simply remove `request` from the call:

```
return redirect('/app02/userinfo/')
```